# Removing Meta Links on the Single Product View

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'd like to keep the meta (Category/Tag) on the Single Product View but remove the links going to their categories if that is possible.

I've tried looking for a hook or snippet that does this but haven't found anything.

Any help would be appreciated.

Tried looking at the meta hook for WC not sure how to edit to just remove link functionality.

Comment: which meta are you talking about? If about Woocommerce Breadcrumbs you could take a look at this article https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/customise-the-woocommerce-breadcrumb/

Comment: hey @gael its the category/tags meta that I want to remove the links from.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this simply with jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.meta-class').removeAttr('href');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this ?

Please try this :

/* Remove product meta */

remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_meta', 40 );

Source : https://gist.github.com/zstepek/597c2091abaac7811bb3